# How to set dynamically the size of the edge in a network plotly + python

Tags: python, data-visualization, plotly

I have build two networks using Plotly. Actually the more connection a node got the more his color become darker. I'm trying to do something similar with the Edge. I would like my edge to be of random size in the same network. I tried all night but couldn't find a way out. You can find the chart I did here (at the end of the note book):

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/melvynator/DM_FinalProject/blob/master/data_exploration/data_exploration.ipynb

I guess I have to set some attribute correctly in the Scatter object of my edges_trace but I try many things and nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an issue discussed in the git project.